# NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration did not call in custom NSURLProtocol's method canInitWithRequest

Tags: nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol

I have a subclass of NSURLProtocol,
The NSURLConnection works well.

And [NSURLSession sharedSession] works well too.

But, [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration] not work,

I called the [NSURLProtocol registerClass:NSURLProtocolSubclass.class];

what's error?

```
NSString * stringUrl = @"https://www.apple.com/";
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
urlRequest.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

NSURLSessionConfiguration * configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20.0;

//this can work, but I cann't edit.
//configuration.protocolClasses = @[NSURLProtocolSubclass.class];

//this can work.
NSURLSession * urlSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

//this not work.
//NSURLSession * urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

//Task.
NSURLSessionDataTask * task = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse * httpUrlResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSLog(@"---- session: %ld", (long)httpUrlResponse.statusCode);
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: First question - why are you using an ephemeral session? I ask because there are very few reasons for ever having to use it.

Comment: I try the defaultSessionConfiguration, the NSURLProtocolSubclass didn't called too.

Comment: ah, should have read the question in more detail. To be honest, I've never worked with NSURLProtocol, so I don't think I can help with that. My apologies. However, using the protocol doesn't necessitate the need for an ephemeral session. To my knowledge, the two APIs don't have much to do with each other. You should be able to simply use the defaultConfiguration.

Comment: Thanks. I just to test all the NSURLSessionConfiguration' type, and forgot to edit back.

Answer (score 7):

The `registerClass` method registers a protocol with NSURLConnection and with the shared session **only**.  Other sessions copy the global set of protocols at the time the session is created, IIRC, unless you provide a custom array, in which case it copies that array.

Ether way, if you need to add protocols while your app is running, I'm pretty sure you have to create a new session each time unless you use the shared session.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I lost several hours in vain until i found this. Thanks.